# Get an order item custom index and assign it to options value In Woocommerce

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I use Woocommerce latest version 3.4.2.
In this case, we collect the order data: the product and its additives ( I take in meta data).

**How to assign the index of variable `$skus[] = $product->get_sku();` as the value of variable `$product_mod[] = '';`?**

`$product_mod[1] = "0";`  // The product ( ingredient Sugar) with key 1 is the product modifier with key 0.

```
// Get product details
$skus = $item_quantities = $line_item_totals = $product_mod = array();

// Loop though order items
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item){
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
    $product = $item->get_product();

    $item_quantities[] = $item->get_quantity();
    $line_item_totals[] = $item->get_total();
    $skus[] = $product->get_sku();
    $product_mod[] = NULL;

    $ai = $item->get_meta('Optionally select');
    if( strpos( $ai, 'Cinnamon' ) !== false ) {
        $skus[] = '10001';
        $item_quantities[] ='1';
        $line_item_totals[] = '50';
        $product_mod[] = '';
    }

    if( strpos( $ai, 'Sugar' ) !== false ) {
        $skus[] = '10002';
        $item_quantities[] ='1';
        $line_item_totals[] = '50';
        $product_mod[] = '';
    }

    if( strpos( $ai, 'Mint' ) !== false ) {
        $skus[] = '10003';
        $item_quantities[] ='1';
        $line_item_totals[] = '50';
        $product_mod[] = '';
    }
}

// Product details
foreach ($skus as $key => $value){
    $data .= "&product_sku[".$key."]=".$value."";
    $data .= "&product_quantity[".$key."]=".$item_quantities[$key]."";
    $data .= "&product_price[".$key."]=".$line_item_totals[$key]."";
    if( isset($product_mod[$key]) ) {
        $data .= "&product_mod[".$key."]=".$key."";
    }
}
```

`print_r( $data );` now show:
// For the convenience of reading, I wrote in a column, but this is a string.

```
&product_sku[0]=10030 
&product_quantity[0]=1
&product_price[0]=499
&product_sku[1]=10002
&product_quantity[1]=1
&product_price[1]=50
&product_mod[1]=1
```

Need:

```
&product_sku[0]=10030 // Coffe sku
&product_quantity[0]=1 // Coffe quantity
&product_price[0]=499 // Coffe price
&product_sku[1]=10002 // Sugar sku
&product_quantity[1]=1 // Sugar quantity
&product_price[1]=50 // Sugar price
&product_mod[1]=0 // Ingredient Sugar with number 1, is a product modifier with number 0.
```

I think this is right way:
[image: Example]

Comment: I had a count offset, but I fixed it by adding a line $product_mod[] = NULL; Now need need to make a binding of the additive of the product to the product.

Comment: `$product_mod[] = 'key(&sku)';` - shows its index, but not the right product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been complicating a bit the thing…  You need to set the main order item index in a variable to get it for your product modifier in the selected additional options. No need of any complications…

I have revisited, simplified and compacted your code:

```
// Array of defined options ( sku => option name )
$options  = array(
    '10001' => 'Cinnamon',
    '10002' => 'Sugar',
    '10003' => 'Mint',
);
$count = 0;

// Loop though order items
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item){
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
    $product    = $item->get_product();

    $data .= '&product_sku['.$count.']='.$product->get_sku();
    $data .= '&product_quantity['.$count.']='.$item->get_quantity();
    $data .= '&product_price['.$count.']='.$item->get_total();
    $ind   = $count; // Here we set the main order item index in a variable
    $count++; 

    // Get order item selected options
    $options_selected = $item->get_meta('Optionally select');

    // Loop though order items selected options
    foreach( $options as $sku_key => $label_value ){
        if( strpos( $options_selected, $label_value ) !== false ) {
            $data .= '&product_sku['.$count.']='.$sku_key;
            $data .= '&product_quantity['.$count.']=1';
            $data .= '&product_price['.$count.']=50';
            $data .= '&product_mod['.$count.']='.$ind;
            $count++;
        }
    }
}

// Testing output
print_r( $data );
```

Untested, but it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a class. That's what they are made for.
That way you will always have your data neatly grouped together the way you want it without the messiness of having to remain an order or multiple arrays.

The class below is just a proof of concept, getters and setters you'll have to make yourself, but if you do it like this, you have control of the data, where it goes, what belongs with what, and you can even move data from one array to another or copy the objects over.

What you do is make your own object that has the product data you want.
Then you add an array in it "extras" where you can "extras" to the product.
Then you add a function to count the total of "own price + price of extras"
And some other helper functions you need.

Then you wrap it up and have a nice class to help you.

Please note, it's pseudo code, will need some work.

```
class ProductData 
{
   protected $product_id;
   protected $product;
   protected $quantity;
   protected $total;
   protected $sku;
   protected $extras = [];

   public function __construct($product_id, $product, $sku, $total, $quantity) 
   {
      $this->product_id = $product_id;
      $this->product = $product;
      $this->sku = $sku;
      $this->total = $total;
      $this->quantity = $quantity;
   }
   public function addExtra($product) 
   {
      $this->extras[] = $product;
   }
   public function getTotal() 
   {
      $total = $this->total;
      foreach($this->extras as $extra)  {
          $this->total += $extra->getTotal();
      }
      return total;
   }
   public static function fromItem($item) 
   {
       $product = new self(
                          $item->get_product_id(),
                          $item->get_product(),
                          $item->get_sku(),
                          $item->line_item_totals(),
                          $item->get_quantity()
                   );
       return $product;

   }
}

$preregistered_extras = [
     'Cinnamon' => new Product(
                             wc_get_product_id_by_sku('10001'), 
                             wc_get_product(wc_get_product_id_by_sku('10001')), 
                             '10001', 
                             '50', 
                             '1'),
     'Sugar' => new Product(
                             wc_get_product_id_by_sku('10002'), 
                             wc_get_product(wc_get_product_id_by_sku('10002')), 
                             '10002', 
                             '50', 
                             '1'),
     'Mint' => new Product(
                             wc_get_product_id_by_sku('10003'), 
                             wc_get_product(wc_get_product_id_by_sku('10003')), 
                             '10003', 
                             '50', 
                             '1'),
];

$product_list = [];
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item){
   $product = Product::fromItem($item);
   $ai = $item->get_meta('Optionally select');

   foreach($preregistered_extras as $name => $extra) {
      if( stripos( $ai, $name ) !== false ) { 
          $product->addExtra($extra);
      }
   }    
}
var_dump($product_list);
$total = 0;
foreach($product_list as $item) {
    $total += $item->getTotal();
}
echo "Total = $total";
```